# Python: find the number of black pixels in images

Tags: opencv, pixel, threshold

I have a video file for image processing. In the video I've captured samples in exact times like figure, thresholded by using OpenCV. Now I want to find differences in the number of black pixels in order to reach the graphic of time vs. difference. How can I find the number of black pixels in each image in Python?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfgrb.png]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV does not offer a function do directly count black pixels but a function to count all pixels that are not black: [cv2.countNonZero(img)](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero)

As you have not posted your code here is a sample how you could use this:

```
# get all non black Pixels
cntNotBlack = cv2.countNonZero(img)

# get pixel count of image
height, width, channels = img.shape
cntPixels = height*width

# compute all black pixels
cntBlack = cntPixels - cntNotBlack
```

Note that this will only find pure black pixel (meaning all channels are exactly zero).

Comment: Couldn't you just invert the image then use the method?

Comment: No, if you invert the image first and then use `countNonZero` you get all pixels but the completly white pixels (as white is now the new black/zero).

Comment: Right, I assumed a completely binary image.  Never mind.

Comment: For a complete binary image this would work exactly as you described :)